# How can a Russian citizen prove they have enough funds to cover a trip without having money in their bank account?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, russian-citizens, scams

When applying for a US B1/B2 visa from Russia and you can fulfill most of the required documents but can only do partially one of the requirements i.e... The passport as one, the airfare for the third but you can only fulfill your earnings statement and your pay-stub at the time of your application, can the travel agent send proof of your financial means to the embassy when you show him/her that you have the funds?

Comment: Since you wrote B1/B2, I am assuming that you want to apply for a US visa, so I added a corresponding tag. Please correct it if this is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, that tag isn't much help. She has shown everything but the money to sustain herself while here in the US and has told me that if she can't show the money part she will be charged with fraud and banned for life.

Comment: "charged with fraud and banned for life" - that's not what happens when you're denied a visa unless you've committed some sort of serious willful infringement. Failure to show sufficient funds is just going to get you a "visa denied, try again if/when you can resolve this issue".

Comment: If I understand this right, you're helping someone (perhaps a lady you met on the internet?) in Russia come to the US to visit you and she's asking you for money, saying that if she doesn't have it she could be charged with fraud and banned for life. Do I have that right?

Comment: Stop. Someone is trying to scam you. We have seen this sort of thing before.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, hang on please. It's not necessarily the signature of a scam given what we know so far

Comment: I don't think we know enough to definitively say it's a scam, but please be careful as there are some red flags. @MatthewChrisBlair Can you tell us a bit more about the situation? Who's asking who for what?

Comment: Zack, You have it right and I don't think in good conscience that I'm not going to send her the money. She has not told the embassy that she is coming to visit me and I'm not cool with it. If she is legitimate I'm not sure that I want to be looking over my shoulder for INS to come knocking at my door looking for her and I don't want to be caught in the middle of an immigration case.I've heard from some people that they can get very ugly.

Comment: @MatthewChrisBlair It sounds like your instincts are good here. This is not an atypical pattern (see, for instance, [this previous question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67744/amount-of-money-needed-to-apply-for-a-b1-b2-us-visa-in-russia#)) where an American meets a Russian woman online, they start talking about a visit to the US, and she comes up with high-pressure tactics (e.g. charged with fraud and banned for life) why you need to send them money. While I can't say for certain what is happening here (travel agents are known to give bad advice), this raises all the red flags.

Answer (score 1):

Scam aside.

There is really not much that can be deemed acceptable as proof of funds for the purpose of the visa.  The issue is not just the availability of funds but also their provenance.

A consulate use paystubs as part of the proof that the applicant will return because they have a legitimate job and the bank statements to proof that the money that the applicant has come from legitimate sources, such as a job, and not from illegal or questionable activities.

There is also a related question related to Schengen visa application but similar logic would apply for the US:

[Proving your financial stability if you are a freelancer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51216/proving-your-financial-stability-if-you-are-a-freelancer)